# How does JDBC implement ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, resultset

When we query a database and retrieve a list of records, let's say we executed this query : `SELECT * FROM students OFFSET 1 LIMIT 100`. If, while we are working with these items, another thread changes one of these records our resultSet object will get updated automatically? If yes then how? Is Java constantly running queries to retrieve the data and compare? Or does the database notify the change? If it's notification from database, could you please give me some examples how MySQL and PostgreSQL do this?

Is it updated if another thread from our Java code updates those records or even if a connection from another source updates it we'll still get updated?

Comment: This is driver specific, and a lot of drivers will actually downgrade requests from TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE to TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE because they don't support it. JDBC doesn't have a lot of requirements, just that it can happen, e.g. when the row is fetched again.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for your answer.
 Do you know any database driver which supports this? and if yes how how they implement it ?